# python getting each from decimal(10,2)

Tags: python, regex

i want to seperate and get each one from following word

```
decimal(10,2)
```

i want:

```
decimal
10
2
```

each of these.how can we do that using regex?

",2" is optional,like in the case of char(10).The Precision value may or may not be there.

Comment: Is `decimal(10,2)` a string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes it is string

Comment: i tried this ,but not working  searchRes = re.search(r'(.*)\((.*)\,(.*)',type1)
        print(searchRes.group(1))

Comment: Attempts should go in the post itself, not buried in a comment. You should also add what it did instead.

Comment: @c0der, That attempt, if you had posted in the question, could not have earned you three downvotes in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `(\w+)(?:\((\d+)(?:,(\d+))?\))?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YHvtsT/3)

Comment: its working for decimal(10,2) .but what if its char(10) .in this case this is giving no match.can you help?

Comment: @c0der, I have updated the regex to support char(10) and bool

Answer (score 0):

Simple string substitution:

```
import re
string = "decimal(10,2)"
string = re.sub(r'(\w+)\((\d+),(\d+)\)', r'\1\n\2\n\3', string)
print string
```